# Why does C++11 not have template typedef?

Tags: c++, c++11, language-lawyer

Why does C++11 not have "template typedefs", like

```
template<typename T> typedef std::vector<T, myalloc<T>> vec;
```

Instead they only allow the new syntax:

```
template<typename T> using vec = std::vector<T, myalloc<T>>;
```

Comment: Maybe look through the references listed in the back of [N2258](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2007/n2258.pdf)?

Comment: Template aliases was a need that was introduced in C++11 and was decided that `using` should be used instead of `typedef`.

Comment: Because the `typedef` syntax is horrible (it *extends variable declaration syntax*!), especially for function types. `using` is way more readable; unless you really need pre-11 compatibility, just replace all your typedefs with `using` and enjoy how much cleaner the code gets.

Comment: I remember this being a duplicate of one other question, but I can't for the life of me find it.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

[n1406](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2002/n1406.pdf) was the proposal by Herb Sutter for "typedef templates" which mimics the syntax in your question. [n1499](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1449.pdf) which proposes "template aliases" supersedes it, which contains the `using` syntax that's currently present in C++11.

One of the main drawbacks of the "typedef templates" is addressed in both papers. From n1406:

> In existing practice, including in the standard library, type names
>   nested inside helper class templates are used to work around this
>   problem in many cases. The following is one example of this usual
>   workaround; the main drawback is the need to write ::Type when using
>   the typedef’d name.
>
> ```
> template< typename T >
> struct SharedPtr
> {
>   typedef Loki::SmartPtr
>     <
>       T,                // note, T still varies
>       RefCounted,       // but everything else is fixed
>       NoChecking,
>       false,
>       PointsToOneObject,
>       SingleThreaded,
>       SimplePointer<T>  // note, T can be used as here
>     >
>   Type;
> };
>
> SharedPtr<int>::Type p; // sample usage, “::Type” is ugly
> ```
>
> What we’d really like to be able to do is simply this:
>
> ```
> template< typename T >
> typedef Loki::SmartPtr
>   <
>     T,                // note, T still varies
>     RefCounted,       // but everything else is fixed
>     NoChecking,
>     false,
>     PointsToOneObject,
>     SingleThreaded,
>     SimplePointer<T>  // note, T can be used as here
>   >
>   SharedPtr;
>
> SharedPtr<int> p;     // sample usage, “::Type” is ugly
> ```
>
> [...]
>
> The workaround is ugly, and it would be good to replace it with
>   first-class language support that offers users a natural C++ template
>   syntax.

That "first-class language support" comes in the form of template aliases. We can now look at what n1499 has to say:

> In this paper we will focus on describing an aliasing mechanism that
>   allows the two semantics mentioned in N1406 to coexist instead being
>   regarded as mutually exclusive. First let’s consider a toy example:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> class MyAlloc {/*...*/};
>
> template <typename T, class A>
> class MyVector {/*...*/};
>
> template <typename T>
> struct Vec {
> typedef MyVector<T, MyAlloc<T> > type;
> };
>
> Vec<int>::type p; // sample usage
> ```
>
> The fundamental problem with this idiom, and the main motivating fact
>   for this proposal, is that the idiom causes the template parameters to
>   appear in non-deducible context. That is, it will not be possible to
>   call the function `foo` below without explicitly specifying template
>   arguments.
>
> ```
> template <typename T> void foo (Vec<T>::type&);
> ```
>
> Also, the syntax is somewhat ugly. We would rather avoid the nested
>   ::type call. We’d prefer something like the following:
>
> ```
> template <typename T>
> using Vec = MyVector<T, MyAlloc<T> >; //defined in section 2 below
>
> Vec<int> p;      // sample usage
> ```
>
> Note that we specifically avoid the term "typedef template" and
>   introduce the new syntax involving the pair "using" and "=" to help
>   avoid confusion: we are not *defining* any types here, we are
>   introducing a synonym (i.e. alias) for an abstraction of a *type-id*
>   (i.e. type expression) involving template parameters. If the template
>   parameters are used in deducible contexts in the type expression then
>   whenever the template alias is used to form a *template-id*, the
>   values of the corresponding template parameters can be deduced – more
>   on this will follow. In any case, it is now possible to write generic
>   functions which operate on `Vec<T>` in deducible context, and the
>   syntax is improved as well. For example we could rewrite `foo` as:
>
> ```
> template <typename T> void foo (Vec<T>&);
> ```
>
> We underscore here that one of the primary reasons for proposing
>   template aliases was so that argument deduction and the call to
>   `foo(p)` will succeed.

So you can see that n1499 addresses the problems in n1406 as well as introducing a syntax that's much cleaner and easier to read.

Comment: Why would `template<typename T> typedef MyVector<T, MyAlloc<T> > Vec;` not solve the problem too?