# Why there is no templated typedef in C++11?

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, typedef, using

Why the Committee decided not to approve templated `typedef` along with templated `using`?

```
template <class T>
using my_vector = std::vector<T>;
```

is legal.

But

```
template <class T>
typedef std::vector<T> my_vector<T>;
```

is illegal?

Upd. The question [Why does C++11 not have template typedef?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27458662/why-does-c11-not-have-template-typedef) is NOT answering.

Comment: Yes. The committee didn't like any of the ways to make `typedef` work with `template`s, so they invented `using` instead. You would need to dig through meeting logs or mailing lists to find out why.

Comment: @nwp That's why I'm asking here: may be someone interested in this in past and already read the logs...

Comment: maybe they could have introduced `templatedef` :D

Comment: @sp2danny He uttered a new keyword! Inquisitor, ban this heretic!

Comment: @cpplearner No, there is no answer, WHY there is no template typedef in C++.

Comment: There is written "This question already **has** an answer here:" and a link. The question HAS NOT answer there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Quoting from the proposal *Templates aliases for C++* [N1489](http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/papers/2003/n1489.pdf) (**Emphasis Mine**):

> **It has been suggested to (re)use the keyword `typedef`** — as done in the paper [4] — to introduce template aliases:
>
> ```
> template<class T>
> typedef std::vector<T, MyAllocator<T> > Vec;
> ```
>
> That notation has the advantage of using a keyword already known to
>   introduce a type alias. However, **it also displays several
>   disavantages among which the confusion of using a keyword known to
>   introduce an alias for a type-name in a context where the alias does
>   not designate a type, but a template;** `Vec` is not an alias for a
>   type, and should not be taken for a `typedef`-name. The name `Vec` is a
>   name for the family `std::vector<., MyAllocator<.>>` – where the bullet is a 
>   placeholder for a type-name. **Consequently we do not propose the “`typedef`” 
>   syntax.**
>
> <sub>[4] Herb Sutter, Typedef templates, document no. WG21/1406.</sub>